# C# Entity Framework Delete child table (relational ) data and update parent table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, parent-child

I am using Entity Framework to update record

| User (Parent) | Email (Child) |
| --- | --- |
| UserId | EmailId |
| UserName | UserId |
|  | EmailAddress |

in Child table , One user has multiple email address. When a user is updating then delete all child data and save the parent and child data. I dont have any issue in adding and deleting User data.

**Please note that I have only Users table DbSet is accessible. I am using some other projects DbContext**

```
Private async Task updateUser(User _user){
var user = _configurationDbContext.Users
                .Include(x => x.Emails)
                .Where(x => x.UserId == _user.UserId)
                .FirstOrDefault();

user.Emails.RemoveAll(x => x.UserId  == _user.Id);

_configurationDbContext.Users.Update(_user);

return await _configurationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

}
```

I am getting the below error

InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Users' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'UserId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Can I know how to achieve this using **Users** DbSet

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two different instances of `User` pointing to the same `UserId`.

As a workaround you could probably do the following:

```
private async Task updateUser(User _user) {
    var user = _configurationDbContext.Users
                .Include(x => x.Emails)
                .Where(x => x.UserId == _user.UserId)
                .FirstOrDefault();
    
    _configurationDbContext.Entry(_user).State = EntityState.Detached;
    user.Emails.RemoveAll(x => x.UserId  == _user.Id);

    _configurationDbContext.Users.Update(user);

    return await _configurationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Beware that changes to `_user` will no longer be tracked by EF automatically after calling `_configurationDbContext.Entry(_user).State = EntityState.Detached;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var user = _configurationDbContext.Users
                .Include(x => x.Emails)
                .Where(x => x.UserId == _user.UserId)
                .FirstOrDefault();

user.Emails.RemoveAll(x => x.UserId  == _user.Id);
// or you can try
user.Emails.Clear();

_configurationDbContext.Entry(user).CurrentValues.SetValues(_user);

return await _configurationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
```